# Sum continuously updating dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am monitoring a device that is continuously updating a dictionary that I would like to add the current and next update of each values in place (eventually to do averaging on the data). The problem is I end up appending to the same dictionary. I am having trouble trying to keep the current dictionary and the next dictionary in the same loop without making it complicated...

```
data = {}
```

iteration 0:

```
data = { 'foo': [1,2,3], 'bar': [2,4,6]}
```

iteration 1:

```
data = { 'foo': [4,3,7], 'bar': [5,1,3]}
```

then sum both

```
datas = { 'foo': [5,5,10], 'bar':[7,5,9]}
```

and so on...

```
from collections import Counter
import random
import time

c = Counter()

def update_dict(data):
    c.update(data) #I want to take the current values and then add it to the next iteration of these values
    print dict(c)


while True:
    blah = {i: random.random() for i in range(5)}
    time.sleep(1)
    update_dict(blah)
```

I supposed I can append the updating dictionary to a list of dictionaries and add them all at some point and then clear the list...

Comment: If this is something that you will be doing a lot,  i suggest that you create your own custom class for this with an override for updates.  This technique is similar  to  a running sum and there are ways to optimize them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would collect the sums as in your example:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

data = {}

def update(new_data):
    for key in new_data:
        if key in data:
            z = zip_longest(data[key], new_data[key], fillvalue = 0)
            data[key] = [sum(i) for i in z]
        else:
            data[key] = new_data[key]

update({'foo': [1,2,3], 'bar': [2,4,6]})
update({'foo': [4,3,7], 'bar': [5,1,3]})

print(data)
```

Comment: Just what I was after. Best I could do at BWWs.

Comment: This is a clear difference between answers from someone at work and someone just starting the weekend.

Comment: Lol. I barely deserve a positive score here.

Answer (score 1):

First, check to see if the key exists. 
If the key exists, then
  newList = [sum (a,b) for a,b in zip (data ('foo'),other_foo)]

Then update. Sorry for sloppy answer. Will fix later if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting sum and zip in a list comprehension. I borrowed those ideas in my answer.